# c++::giving exception through throw catch in defining class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, throw

I am trying to throw exception.

```
templete<typename t>
class test{
.
.
.
t test1(){
    if(...){
        throw "exception";
    }
    else{
        return(....);
    }
}
}
```

then in int main try-catch

```
int main(){
try{
    cout<<test1();
}
catch(const char *e){
     cout<<e<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

please suggest how can i use try-catch in class test so that i don't need in int main.
as suggested by commenter i am including simple code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename t>
class test{
public:
    t b;
    test(){
        cin>>b;
    }
    t testresult(t a){
        if(b==a){
            throw "Same";
         }
         a=b;
         return a;

    }
    };
int main(){
        try{
            test<int> d;
            int a;
            cin>>a;
            cout<<d.testresult(a);
            return 0;}
        catch(const char *e){
            cout<<"exception_"<<e<<endl;
        }
}
```

also tried using try catch in test1, but it print integer or string etc. as my datatype t

Comment: You're throwing a string but catching a single character.

Comment: Is the problem that you are throwing a `const char *` and catching a `const char`? Maybe you should throw `std::runtime_exception` or something like that.

Comment: You mean `try-catch` in the constructor of class `test`?

Comment: Oh, and please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question to include that instead of your current (non-compiling) code.

Comment: Put the try-catch inside `test1`, perhaps?

Comment: @nwp i am throwing const char * and catching a const char. sorry for typo

Comment: if your code is alike your sample you are just creating a VERY complicated if then else - don't use try catch for control flow

Comment: @molbdnilo I tried but it give a random number or string as my datatype of t.

Comment: maybe create a function `print_test1` and catch the exception there: http://ideone.com/rEL686

Comment: @Dharmendra The function returned nonsense because you forgot to return a `t` from the function. Unless you return *something* in all cases, the program is invalid.

Comment: @molbdnilo after throw if i add return it also give same nonsense

Comment: @Dharmendra Since you throw an exception and catch it outside the function, it doesn't return at all. How are you determining that it's returning "nonsense"? (The lifetime of `d` ends before the exception is caught, so there's no point looking at its member.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...just use try-catch

```
t testresult(){
    try{
        if(...){
            throw "exception";
        }
        else{
            return(....);
        }
    }
    catch(const char *e){
        cout<<e<<endl;
    }
}
```

---

Assuming your code in [your live example link](http://code.hackerearth.com/24e2ffU?key=6bfb7d8b6012e579b2f51102e60b46bc]), *not your code in your question*, That's not IDE's bug - it's **your fault**.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename t>
class test{
public:
    t b;
    test(){
        cin>>b;
    }
    t testresult(t a){
        try{
        if(b==a){
            throw "Same";
         }
         else{
            a=b;
            return a;
         }
         }
         catch(const char *e){
         cout<<"Exception_"<<e; // here
         }
    }
    };
int main(){
            test<int> d;
            int a;
            cin>>a;
            cout<<d.testresult(a);
            return 0;
}
```

Look at `// here`. you must return any value of type `t`, but you **didn't**!

---

Um, when it comes to your code *in your question*, You probably didn't provide any inputs. (Some IDEs require it before running program)

First, look at the [normal case](http://ideone.com/GSxGGw), providing the inputs.

[image]

And look at the another case, providing no inputs.

[image]

Comment: it prints random number or string or others  as my datatype t after exception

Comment: Why not just `if(...) { cout << "exception" << end; } else { return ...' }`?

Comment: @dornhege it removes the benefits of try catch. It's very useful because it can separate the *main code* and *exception handler code*. Suppose that the `else` block is very very long and have more `throw`s.

Comment: @Dharmendra What?? um.. can you give me [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @ikh i am giving sample code [http://code.hackerearth.com/24e2ffU?key=6bfb7d8b6012e579b2f51102e60b46bc]. it works fine on Code::Blocks 13.12 , but it print random number after Exception.but i think it is **IDE** specific problem

Comment: @Dharmendra No, your code is *illegal*. See my edit.